# Contribution - Invoice Address layout is wrong. How to fix?

Tags: pdf, invoice

I am on Civi 5.0.1 and Wordpress 4.9
Please see screenshots.
I need to print and mail some Contribution invoices. I noticed that the address layout for the invoices is incorrect.  I went to Administrator > Communications > Messages Templates > System Workflow Messages.  Then I clicked to Edit Contributions - Invoice.

I tried rearranging some of the tables and short codes to make it show up the way I need it to, but that just messed it up even more.

Can someone tell me the proper table and shortcode arrangement in Contributions - Invoice to get the address layout I need?

Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initially i thought the address are rendered using format defined at Address Settings but i was wrong when i checked the message template. The message template is designed to use address format as

```
Street Address Supplement Address
Supplement Address State Abbreviation
City Postal Code
Country
```

I did some modification to message template so that State Abbreviation is between City and Postal Code. Can you try after replacing the content of **Contributions - Invoice** message template with the content from [here](https://gist.github.com/pradpnayak/6a3c10d598634068b8e7cbc16c7322d9)?

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: wow... cheerz!!!